# deprecated concat operator in RxJS epic

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have an epic works well with concat operator. Webstorm starts saying it is deprecated in the way I use it. Says

> deprecated export function concat<{type: string}[]>(     v1: {type: string}[],     scheduler: SchedulerLike): Observable>
>   Use scheduled and concatAll (e.g. scheduled([o1, o2, o3], scheduler).pipe(concatAll())

Can't figure out, how to rewrite this code?

```
const epic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(TYPE),
  mergeMap(() =>
    concat(
      of({type: 'START'}),
      ajax.getJSON('someurl').pipe(
        mergeMap(serverResponse => ([
          {type: 'LOADED'},
          {type: 'DO_JOB', serverResponse}
        ]))
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a deprecation in your case.

The deprecation affect only concat with scheduler parameter. (an other signature of the function). (See other similar issue: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4723)

You can use:

```js
// tslint:disable-next-line:deprecation
concat(...);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use concatWith. concatWith is actually not a completely new operator. It’s only meant to replace the concat operator which is currently marked as deprecated and will be removed in v8.

There’s one subtle difference between the two, though. concatWith only accepts inputs of type ObservableInput, whereas concat can also take a scheduler.

More details can be found [here](https://dzhavat.github.io/2020/01/11/new-in-rxjs-v7-concatwith-operator.html)